# Float.valueOf(String arg) rounding off issue in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, type-conversion

People,
I stumbled upon a basic issue in my application where am trying to convert a string value to it's corresponding Float value :

```
Float val = obj.getFloat("220293.43") ;
System.out.println(val);
```

Definition of getFloat() :

```
Float getFloat(String arg)
{

return Float.valueOf( arg ) ;

}
```

Now the problem is that when I print the value of converted float, it's giving me :

```
220293.44
```

which is clearly incorrect. Could anyone help me on this, I read a little about this and am suspecting the issue is because of float's limited capacity to support 4 byte of data, but I need a confirmation as well as explanation why this might be happening.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is generally known as the floating point accuracy problems. Not all real numbers can exactly be represented by floating point values therefore there are rounding issues like the one described by you. This is especially odd if you're comparing values that look the same but aren't the same in the internal representation.

[Floating-point arithmetic, Accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems)

Is there a need for using Float in your case?

Comment: I understand that not all real numbers can't be expressed exactly by floating numbers, could explain me why it's failing in this particular scenario of "220293.43" ?

Comment: you just found a concrete example for float accuracy problems with exactly your number of choice - if you would dig into the binary representation of this number you would find the solution by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

float has only 24 bits of precision.

You must use double if you require floating value

Comment: I know double is solving that problem, I want to understand why it is failing in "220293.43" scenario. Even if I use '220293.430' result is same.